# How to run an HTML file which resides on my system from another system through apache server?

Tags: html, apache

Actually I want to run an html file in my client's system in which the html file  resides in my system.

Comment: Do you have a windows machine or unix machine?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:apache]. What problem are you having with it? Have you read [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/getting-started.html)?

Comment: I think your question is a little ambiguous, could you be clearer as to what you mean by 'my system'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your Html file on other system use, http://systemipaddress:8080/yourfile.html.
Also, if you want to run your Html file in your system, then give http://localhost:8080/yourfile.html. whereas "systemipaddress" is the IP address of your file residing system.

Comment: To do this you should keep running your server and your client server in respective systems.